# Improving Column Grouping Speed in Microsoft Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, pivot

I am doing a large application where I am using column grouping in my reports.  Unfortunately, the performance is pitifully slow, and my customer is complaining about it.  As an example, if they run a report for a 24 hour period, it takes ~10 minutes to return (~800 display pages of data).  If they run it for a month, it may never return!

The query itself for a 24 hour period returns in ~20 seconds.  The balance of the time is pivoting and generating the report.

Do you have any suggestions as what I could do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Reporting Services has three stages in creating a report:

- Data retrieval (executing the queries to return the dataset results)
- Processing  (grouping and aggregating the returned data according to
  the report layout)
- Rendering  (generating the selected output, e.g.
  HTML, Excel)

If your query returns data in ~20 seconds but the report takes 10 minutes to render, then the main issue is with the speed of the report processing (rendering is rarely a performance bottleneck), as you rightly assumed. The best way to improve performance is to off load as much of the aggregation as possible to the source database by re-writing your query to do the aggregating there. The database platform is usually much faster at aggregating data than Reporting Services. Ideally you want to return the minimum amount of data required for the report so that it has as little processing to do as possible.

If you have access to the ReportServer database, run this query to confirm where the bottleneck is:

```
SELECT ItemPath, Format, TimeStart, TimeEnd, TimeDataRetrieval, TimeProcessing, TimeRendering, [Status], ByteCount, [RowCount] 
FROM ExecutionLog3
WHERE ItemPath LIKE '%My Report Name%'
```

TimeDataRetrieval, TimeProcessing and TimeRendering should give you a clear idea of where the problem lies. If the issue is with TimeProcessing then try and rewrite the query to reduce the data for the report and also review the [possible design issues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522806%28v=sql.105%29.aspx#Process) to see if any of them apply.

Comment: Thank you for the advice...  The main problem with the report processing is the use of column groups, and the associated pivoting that accompanies these groups.  I re-wrote the query to pivot in the associated stored procedure, however the performance dropped so low I wasn't even able to come up with a time that it now took to query the data; I gave up on the query before it returned!  I used both the PIVOT command, and also did the pivot manually.

Comment: The query is actually quite simple, and aside from the pivoting of the result set, there is not a lot going on.  It is a two table inner join - nothing unusual.  However, there is a lot of "logic" in the report.  Things like color coding cells, showing/hiding columns based on other fields, hyperlinks, etc.  How much do these factors contribute as opposed to the column grouping itself?

Comment: Do you know what the performance is of other reports on this server? Just trying to work out if you have a server issue or a report issue.

Comment: Adding features like hiding rows etc does make the report more complex to render but in my experience not noticeably longer to render. The majority of the total time is usually data retrieval, so this is something unusual in my experience. You might need to start a new report with the same dataset, then add a simple table or matrix and test the render time, adding more formatting and retesting for speed each time to work out where the bottleneck is.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you are sorting on the report side as opposed to the query side. This can speed things up. Sorting groups or sorting by aggregate values is much simpler in the report than in the query and is frequently more efficient also.

Take a look at these tips for speeding up performance.
[Troubleshooting Reports: Report Performance](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522806%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)